# Read image and access bytes in boost::gil

Tags: c++, image, boost, boost-gil

Is it possible to:

- read an image given by just a filename (not knowing the image format) to a 2d matrix rgb uncompressed form (e.g. read an JPG to a 2d array)
- access the bytes of that image, copy them, change them... (e.g. inverse the colors, ***I need a pointer to the image bytes, setters/getters won't do*** )
- save those bytes to any given image format (e.g. save the inversed image to PNG)

Is it possible with `boost::gil` ? Maybe there is a different library more appropriate for such a task?

Sample code would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do all that in `boost::gil`. 
What you should know though, is that `boost::gil` is only a universal interface and doesn't handle reading/writing images all by itself. You still need to use a second library, e.g. libpng..

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, yes** and **yes.**

There are functions that enable you to read *and* write JPEG, TIFF and PNG images: see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/gil/doc/html/group___i_o.html).

For the second bullet, it is what just GIL is meant to do. You can manipulate images using its facilities ([click here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/gil/doc/html/index.html)).

Comment: could you supply a simple example for each bullet? I ma trying to verify in `boost::gil` is as simple to use as OpenCV's `Mat` class..

Comment: I haven't really tried GIL but, still, see: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html. See its sample files (at the bottom).

Comment: @Queequeg Sorry. Please see my above comment.

Comment: Okay - one last thing, that seems to be hidden behind nested templates and the like: can I access raw bytes of the image? Can I copy those bytes to a char* ?

Comment: portable way to access to pixels is to use the view concept. Non-portable method, userful for rgb8_image_t: http://pastebin.com/pt5QDDbY